# Setting Timestamps on files/directories is extremely slow

Tags: c#, winapi, io, filesystems

I'm working on a project, which requires to copy a lot of files and directories, while preserving their original timestamps. So I need to make many calls to the target's `SetCreationTime()`, `SetLastWriteTime()` and `SetLastAccessTime()` methods in order to copy the original values from source to target. As the screenshot below shows, these simple operations take up to 42% of the total computation time.

[image: performance analysis]

Since this is limiting my whole application's performance tremendously, I'd like to speed things up. I assume, that each of these calls requires to open and close a new stream to the file/directory. If that's the reason, I'd like to leave this stream open until I finished writing all attributes. How do I accomplish this? I guess this would require the use of some P/Invoke.

**Update:**

I followed **Lukas' advice** to use the WinAPI method `CreateFile(..)` with the `FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES`. In order to P/Invoke the mentioned method I created following wrapper:

```
public class Win32ApiWrapper
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(string lpFileName,
                                                    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileAccess dwDesiredAccess,
                                                    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileShare dwShareMode,
                                                    IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes, 
                                                    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileMode dwCreationDisposition,
                                                    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileAttributes dwFlagsAndAttributes,
                                                    IntPtr hTemplateFile);

    public static SafeFileHandle CreateFileGetHandle(string path, int fileAttributes)
    {
        return CreateFile(path,
                (FileAccess)(EFileAccess.FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES | EFileAccess.FILE_WRITE_DATA),
                0,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                FileMode.Create,
                (FileAttributes)fileAttributes,
                IntPtr.Zero);
        }
}
```

The enums I used can be found [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.createfile).This allowed me to do all all things with only opening the file once: Create the file, apply all attributes, set the timestamps and copy the actual content from the original file.

```
FileInfo targetFile;
int fileAttributes;
IDictionary<string, long> timeStamps; 

using (var hFile = Win32ApiWrapper.CreateFileGetHandle(targetFile.FullName, attributeFlags))
using (var targetStream = new FileStream(hFile, FileAccess.Write))
{
    // copy file
    Win32ApiWrapper.SetFileTime(hFile, timeStamps);
}
```

**Was it worth the effort?** YES. It reduced computation time by ~40% from 86s to 51s.

Results before optimization:

[image: before]

Results after optimization:

[image: after]

Comment: See http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,63bd669b43be5f17 for the implementation of `File.SetCreationTimeUtc`. You probably want to write a function that P/Invokes `CreateFile` followed by `SetFileTime`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not a C# programmer and I don't know how those System.IO.FileSystemInfo methods are implemented. But I've made a few tests with the WIN32 API function [SetFileTime(..)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724933%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which will be called by C# at some point.

Here is the code snippet of my benchmark-loop:

```
#define NO_OF_ITERATIONS   100000

int iteration;
DWORD tStart;
SYSTEMTIME tSys;
FILETIME tFile;
HANDLE hFile;
DWORD tEllapsed;


iteration = NO_OF_ITERATIONS;
GetLocalTime(&tSys);
tStart = GetTickCount();
while (iteration)
{
   tSys.wYear++;
   if (tSys.wYear > 2020)
   {
      tSys.wYear = 2000;
   }

   SystemTimeToFileTime(&tSys, &tFile);
   hFile = CreateFile("test.dat",
                      GENERIC_WRITE,   // FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES
                      0,
                      NULL,
                      OPEN_EXISTING,
                      FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                      NULL);
   if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
   {
      printf("CreateFile(..) failed (error: %d)\n", GetLastError());
      break;
   }

   SetFileTime(hFile, &tFile, &tFile, &tFile);

   CloseHandle(hFile);
   iteration--;
}
tEllapsed = GetTickCount() - tStart;
```

I've seen that the expensive part of setting the file times is the opening/closing of the file. About 60% of the time is used to open the file and about 40% to close it (which needs to flush the modifications to disc). The above loop took about 9s for 10000 iterations.

A little research showed that calling `CreateFile(..)` with `FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES` (instead of `GENERIC_WRITE`) is sufficient to change the time attributes of a file.

This modification speed things up significantly! Now the same loop finishes within 2s for 10000 iterations. Since the number of iterations is quite small I've made a second run with 100000 iterations to get a more reliable time measurement:

- FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES: 5 runs with 100000 iterations: 12.7-13.2s
- GENERIC_WRITE: 5 runs with 100000 iterations: 63.2-72.5s

Based on the above numbers my guess is that the C# methods use the wrong access mode when opening the file to change to file time. Or some other C# behavior slows things down...

So maybe a solution to your speed issue is to implement a DLL which exports a C function which changes the file times using `SetFileTime(..)`? Or maybe you can even import the functions `CreateFile(..)`, `SetFileTime(..)` and `CloseHandle(..)` directly to avoid calling the C# methods?

Good luck!

Comment: Wow, thanks for this detailed answer! I will try to use the `FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES`, this should solve my problem.

Comment: No need to write a DLL that does that. You can write a C# function that calls the Windows API functions.